# How do I get multiple side by side divs to move down together instead of moving down one by one as window size is decreased

Tags: html, css

I have a row of divs:
[row of divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bogLj.png)

When I decrease the window size they move down and stack on top of one another
[divs stacked on top of one another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSo5k.png)
[another example of the divs stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmm7t.png)

Instead of having them move down one by one as the window size gets smaller I want them to all move down together to the next row like so:
[how I would like the divs to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueph2.png)

How would I go about doing this using divs? or if there is another method (like flex boxes) please let me know. Thanks!

Here is all the relevant code:

```
        <div style="margin-left:3%">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="color:white; float:left; margin-top:1%">


                <div>
                    <h2 style="color:white;"><b>Register by tommorow for the best rate!</b></h2>
                    <p class="b2">
                        Special rates for teams of 3+ 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6 pricing-boxes" style="display:inline-block; ">
                <div class="pricing-box" style="margin-right: 10px; "><p style="font-size:50px"><b>$1495</b></p><p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">MEMBERS</p></div>
                <div class="pricing-box" style="margin-right: 10px; "><p style="font-size:50px"><b>$1495</b></p><p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">NON-MEMBERS</p></div>
                <div class="pricing-box"><p style="font-size:50px"><b>$2000</b></p><p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">VIPS</p></div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" style="color:white; margin-top:2%; margin-left:3%">
            <p class="b1">Register Now and recieve 5,000,000</p>
            <form style="margin-top:-15px;">

                <input style="vertical-align: middle; width:80%; height: auto; font-size:24px; color:black;" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
                <input style="vertical-align: middle; height:auto; font-size: 28px; margin-left:15px;" class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
            </form>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" value="accept">
                <label for="vehicle1"> I agree to receive information and updates</label><br>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.register_container {
        background-color: #00205B;
        width: 80%;
        transform: translateX(12%);
        display: inline-block;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: -175px;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #35353d;
    }

    .pricing-boxes {
        display: flex;
        
       
    }

    .pricing-box {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        margin-top: 7%;
        text-align: center;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to consider a few points

you need to make div responsive in small screen devices by adding `col-12` before `col-md-6`.

if you're using bootstrap then learn it well and you don't need to use inner css.

replace this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 pricing-boxes" style="display:inline-block; ">
<div class="pricing-box" style="margin-right: 10px; "><p style="font-size:50px"><b>$1495</b></p><p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">MEMBERS</p></div>
<div class="pricing-box" style="margin-right: 10px; "><p style="font-size:50px"><b>$1495</b></p><p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">NON-MEMBERS</p></div>
<div class="pricing-box"><p style="font-size:50px"><b>$2000</b></p><p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">VIPS</p></div>
</div>
```

with this:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 pricing-boxes">
    <div class="pricing-box"><h2><b>$1495</b></h2><h6>MEMBERS</h6></div>
    <div class="pricing-box"><h2><b>$1495</b></h2><h6>NON-MEMBERS</h6></div>
    <div class="pricing-box"><h2><b>$2000</b></h2><h6>VIPS</h6></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` and when size of screen is reduced to specific size then apply `width: %` to class `.pricing-boxes` like used in below snippet.

> Use padding and margins according to need

```css
.register_container {
  background-color: #00205B;
  width: 80%;
  transform: translateX(12%);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -175px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #35353d;
}

.pricing-boxes {
  display: flex;
}

.pricing-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 7%;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {/*Value may be from where it start stacking*/
  .pricing-boxes{
    width: 100%;
    /*adjust padding and margin according to need*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:3%">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="color:white; float:left; margin-top:1%">


    <div>
      <h2 style="color:black;"><b>Register by tommorow for the best rate!</b></h2>
      <p class="b2">
        Special rates for teams of 3+
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-6 pricing-boxes" style="display:inline-block; ">
    <div class="pricing-box" style="margin-right: 10px; ">
      <p style="font-size:50px"><b>$1495</b></p>
      <p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">MEMBERS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-box" style="margin-right: 10px; ">
      <p style="font-size:50px"><b>$1495</b></p>
      <p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">NON-MEMBERS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-box">
      <p style="font-size:50px"><b>$2000</b></p>
      <p style="font-size:23px; margin-top:-30px">VIPS</p>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12" style="color:white; margin-top:2%; margin-left:3%">
  <p class="b1">Register Now and recieve 5,000,000</p>
  <form style="margin-top:-15px;">

    <input style="vertical-align: middle; width:80%; height: auto; font-size:24px; color:black;" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
    <input style="vertical-align: middle; height:auto; font-size: 28px; margin-left:15px;" class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
  </form>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" value="accept">
    <label for="vehicle1"> I agree to receive information and updates</label><br>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```